# 401(k) losing money, considering withdrawal to pay off mortgage

Tags: united-states, 401k, retirement, home-ownership, losses

I left my job 13 years ago with $80,000 in a 401(k) plan and $500 a month pension. Two  years ago the company told me that I had to get money for pension. I had already lost $45,000 of my 401(k) due to market drops.

When I cashed in my pension I got $50,000 from it.  I rolled the remainder of 401(k)s plus pension into a 401(k) with a financial adviser with a total investment of $100,000.00.

I figure that I  am down $100,000 over the past 13 years  as my 401(k) continues to drop.  I think that it would be better to pay off my house with the 401(k) money and put my house payment money under a mattress to at least have a potential profit when I sell my house All I have done is lose money with a 401(k) plan.

Comment: You can't have a "401(k)" with a financial advisor, 401(k) plans are offered by _employers_ to their _employees_ and you are not an employee of your financial advisor. Is it instead an IRA? Or did you, God forbid, buy a tax-deferred  annuity with the money (vastly beneficial to the person (financial advisor) who sold it to you but a poor choice for you)?

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Even a tax-deferred annuity would not be as bad as what OP describes -- it would lose out on gains which is a huge missed opportunity, but it wouldn't actually decline in value.

Comment: Honestly, I think the only ways you could lose money are if your financial advisor is ripping you off, or if you insist on putting money in speculative "investments".  Move the IRA/401k to decent index funds with a reputable company like Vanguard or T. Rowe Price.

Comment: For perspective, here is an article written this week:  "Last year witnessed the end of a nine-year run for stocks that saw the S&P 500 deliver a remarkable 259% in total returns and gain 10% or more in seven of those nine years".

Comment: Even including the last two "crashes", the S&P 500 has doubled from 2006 to today. So either you are getting ripped off or your estimates are wrong.

Comment: To follow up on comments about how the 401k (or IRA) might be losing money...  are you making withdrawals regularly (perhaps to live on)?  That $500/month from the pension presumably was going toward living expenses, so it has to be made up from somewhere.  That would account for a steady drop in account balance better than a shady financial advisor (which is the next best option).

Answer (score -3):

A 401K can be in any type of security. So a 401K doesn't fundamentally lose value but what can lose value is the choice of securities. For instance, a 401K could be in six-month corporate bonds or in 2-year government bonds if a more stable investment is wanted.

All the 401K needs to do as a minimum is match inflation, avoid taxes, and compound. However, to be better than paying off a mortgage, the 401K needs to outperform the mortgage rate. Well, the 401K does avoid taxes and that's a bump up.